# How am I playing on the installation disc?

Tags: xbox-one, saints-row-iv

I own an Xbox one and I just bought Saints Row IV (for the Xbox 360). Since its backwards compatible for the Xbox one, I popped in the installation disc, expecting that when the download was done I would take that disc out and put in the actual game disc, but somehow, I’m able to play the game by just using the installation disc. I’m confused here—-is the actual game disc different than the installation disc if I’m somehow able to play on the installation disc??

Answer (score 2):

For backward compatible games you installed using a disc, the disc is only used to verify yoru ownership of the game (DRM). All game content was provided and installed by the download. Hence, the installation disc suffices to verify the ownership and play the game from your back-compat catalogue.